# include php file many times

Tags: php, html

I want a include a .php file to another one. But I want to do it many times. For each one I am going to pass concrete parameters. I want to print the result page on load.

for example imagin I have a html like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="#friend1">
            Name: <input/>
            Age: <input />
        </div>
        <div id="#friend2">
            Name: <input/>
            Age: <input />
        </div>
        <button>print</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have another file wich prints friends info in a cool wai like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            Yo are my friend<?php echo $_SESSION['friend']?> you are <?php echo $_SESSION['age']?>              
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to include this file with concrete info in order to print it. I have been trying with include o require with no succeed. Just one of them is shown. Parameters are passed correctly and I don-t know how to make it.

Any Ideas? Thank you, very much!

I'll try to be more specific:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
        require_once ("jqdirectPrint.js");
    ?>
</script>
<body onload="printLoad();">
     <?php 
         for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['friendList']); $i++) {
              $_SESSION['friend']=$_SESSION['friendList'][$i];
              require 'friendInfo.php';
         }
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

friendInfor.php is just a html form which shows info for concrete friend. But just the first one is shown. I want to show same form for each elemnt on the list. It just contains  tags.

Comment: You have two HTML documents here and no PHP. Simply including the second in the first will break your HTML because it includes `<html>` and `<body>` tags already. I'm not even sure I really understand what your final result should be. Post a sample of the expected output and the PHP you've already written, if you have some.

Comment: Can you show your code with `include()` or `require()`?

Comment: Is the file you're trying to include the other with, `.php` extension? Show us what you're **really** using and how.

Comment: Magic answers will not suddenly appear. Answer the questions from comments above.

Comment: Magic answers appear all the time, but they're just illusions. @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Now you see 'em, now you don't* – @JayBlanchard

Comment: I hope last edit will show better what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth it to just do some more tutorials on basic PHP, then try something again and only after that return here with questions. I think your knownledge of PHP needs a bit more work.

Comment: Can you tell me about an interesting PHP tutorial to consult?

Answer (score 0):

Hobo Sapiens was right I had some extra   tags on my friendInfo.php so I removed them and it worked fine. So thank you for your help. `require`allows you to introduce or load same file many times.

Still waitting for some nice PHP manuals to check. ;)